# microsoft excel COUNTIF/IF and CONCATENATE Issue

Tags: excel, ms-office, countif

I am trying to combine data from 4 different columns and count them.

The criteria would be If item is in 2018 only(first column) and "active","dead","pending" only (second column) and shows as "submitted","not started"(third column) and only people named "chris"(4th column) requested submission, then add all the results together.

So the result i want would be a total of any active,dead or pending deals that occurred in 2018 only(excluding all other years) that are showing as a submitted or not started status submitted by Chris.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Look into `COUNTIFS`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a pivot table.  There is no need to reinvent the wheel.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, I already have pivot tables so i appreciate the comment. Unfortunately for all the different detailed data I have to go through I have about 12 pivot tables and have to re do them every 2 weeks so its very inefficient and time consuming.